# верстка меню, всё мосштабируется, но нижняя половина кнопок 10,11,12 вылезает за экран

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="10"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="11"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="12"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: и вы хотите...? Продолжите фразу

Comment: А есть ли приз тому, кто угадает, чего вы хотите?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то Вам необходимо изменить значение `android:layout_weight` первых двух `LinearLayout` на `2`, в таком случае, масштабирование будет корректным.

Answer (score 1):

Я попробовала на устройстве вашу разметку. Кроме описанного в названии вопроса недостатка обнаружилось, что два верхних `TextView` не видны.

Обе проблемы решаются заменой `android:layout_height="match_parent"` во вложенных `LinearLayout` на `android:layout_height="0dp"`. Внешний `LinearLayout` оставляем без изменений!